# Error con una libreria de Autocompletar de Bootstrap (PHP Y MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

agradezco todos los días que me ayudan a solucionar mis problemas que tengo, he consutado varias veces a ustedes y me han ayudado bastante, la realidad es que he estado aprendiendo sobre sistemas web y ahora tengo un problema y no sé que se me está pasando por alto.

Estoy realizando un sistema web de incapacidades de empleados, lo que logré hacer es que cuando yo ingreso el nombre del empleado se autocompletan unos campos que yo necesito, entonces, cuando ya me trae los nombres de los empleados los nombres me aparecen como "undefined", entonces comparto los códigos que estoy usando y no sé como pueda solucionarse:

Archivo consulta2.php:

```
<?php
include "conn.php";
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
$conn -> set_charset("utf8");
$term = $conn -> real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
$return_arr = array();
 
if ($query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombres LIKE '%$term%' LIMIT 0 ,50")){
    while ($obj = $query->fetch_object()) {
        $row_array['id'] = $obj->id;
        $row_array['cedula'] = $obj->cedula;
        $row_array['nombres'] = $obj->nombres;
        $row_array['cargo'] = $obj->cargo;
        $row_array['proceso'] = $obj->proceso;
        $row_array['nucleo'] = $obj->nucleo;
        $row_array['eps'] = $obj->eps;
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
 
    $query->close();
}
 
echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```

Y utilizo un js de autocompletado que es el siguiente:

```
const autoCompleteConfig = [{
    name: '(*) Nombres: ',
    debounceMS: 250,
    minLength: 2,
    maxResults: 10,
    inputSource: document.getElementById('nombres'),
    targetID: document.getElementById('id'),
    fetchURL: 'consulta2.php?term={term}',
    fetchMap: {id: "id",
               nombres: "nombres"}
  }
];

console.log(autoCompleteConfig);

autocompleteBS(autoCompleteConfig);
 
function resultHandlerBS(inputName, selectedData) {
    document.getElementById('id').value=selectedData.id;
    document.getElementById('cedula').value=selectedData.cedula;
    document.getElementById('cargo').value=selectedData.cargo;
    document.getElementById('proceso').value=selectedData.proceso;
    document.getElementById('nucleo').value=selectedData.nucleo;
    document.getElementById('eps').value=selectedData.eps;
}
```

Los campos que necesito que se llenen automaticamente lo hacen pero el conflicto esta en el nombre del empleado, los input que se llenan son los siguientes:

```
                        <div class="input-group shadow-sm autocompleteBS">
                        <span class="input-group-text w-25" for="nombres">(*) Nombres: </span>
                                <input name="nombres" id="nombres" class=" form-control span8 tip" type="text" required>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="input-group shadow-sm">
                            <span class="input-group-text w-25" for="id">ID: </span>
                            <input name="id" id="id" class="form-control" type="text" readonly required>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="input-group shadow-sm">
                        <span class="input-group-text w-25" for="cedula">Cédula: </span>
                                <input name="cedula" id="cedula" class=" form-control" type="number" placeholder="cedula" required readonly>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="input-group shadow-sm">
                        <span class="input-group-text w-25" for="cargo">Cargo: </span>
                                <input name="cargo" id="cargo" class=" form-control" type="text" placeholder="cargo" required readonly>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="input-group shadow-sm">
                            <span class="input-group-text w-25" for="proceso">Proceso: </span>
                                <input name="proceso" id="proceso" class=" form-control" type="number" placeholder="proceso" required readonly>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="input-group shadow-sm">
                            <span class="input-group-text w-25" for="nucleo">Nucleo: </span>
                                <input name="nucleo" id="nucleo" class=" form-control" type="text" placeholder="nucleo" required readonly>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="input-group shadow-sm">
                            <span class="input-group-text w-25" for="eps">EPS: </span>
                                <input name="eps" id="eps" class=" form-control" type="text" placeholder="eps" required readonly>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
```

Entonces no sé que pasa, me imagino que será un error en la consulta, he investigado sobre el tema pero las soluciones que encuentro no me funcionan, entonces me he quedado sin opciones y no se que hacer ahora.

Sería de gran ayuda que me dijeran en que esta fallando el sistema, saludos y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He logrado solucionar el problema de los "undefined" que me traía la consulta, simplemente cambie el parámetro de la consulta $term por solo el signo de %.